# Infinite loop error when using delimited repeating table from InfoPath

Tags: infopath, sharepoint-online

I am using a form template from infoPath 2007. The form has a repeating table.

When the user enters data into a field I want a delimiter to append to the end of the line- so that I can easily export and manipulate in Excel.

(i.e. the user enters a customer name & a ";" is automatically appended)

For example this is the formula for customer:

```
  xdMath:Eval(.., 'concat(my:Customer, ";")')
```

However, I am recieving the following error in SharePoint:

```
  Default values, rules or code may be running in an infinite loop. To prevent this,  ensure that the default value, rule action or event handler does not update the data which causes the same rule action or event handler to execute. Correlation ID:e9cd4235-c144-469d-9331-1b2c04107487
```

Visually- if I type a customer name into the table instead of one ";" 17 ";"'s are returned (hence the infinite loop). I know what the problem is, I just don't know how to fix it...

Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression should look something like so:

```
xdMath:Eval(xdMath:Eval(group, 'concat(d:Customer, ";")'), "..")
```